# How do I use a varible url for that uses a html to populate the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

so my web page is http://localhost:7777/newdev/art.html which points to my html art.html doc. I wanna acces that html using a different utl like: http://localhost:7777/newdev/data/. I would just like a verrry simple way to go to that url and pull up the art.html.

I have tried adding the html at the end and also changing the rest service to look for the http://localhost:7777/newdev/art.html.

```
$scope.done = function(){
    $scope.major = "";
    $scope.picked = document.getElementsByClassName("math").value + "," + document.getElementsByClassName("Science").value + "," + document.getElementsByClassName("Music").value + "," + document.getElementsByClassName("Art").value+ "," + document.getElementsByClassName("ss").value;
    var url=  'done.html/';
    url+= '?id='+$scope.picked;

    window.open(url);
};
```

Expected results: I will go to http://localhost:7777/newdev/data/ and it will pull up my html document.

Actual result: The rest service doesn't get called or the html doesn't open

Things to think about: This is not for a large website, its for just a side project that is going to stay on my machine and only be ran locally for learning purposes. I am looking for the simple most basic why to do this so it'll give me a platform to grow a learn from.

Comment: Do you mean you want to access your URLs without having to have .html at the end of them?

Comment: Which language are you using in the backend?

Comment: Java in the back end. Yes I want it with out the html but also i want to put variables in the url for my rest services. So i would like the url to be a variable that I can set on the fly